# Login to web server Authentication user not admin

Tags: windows, authentication, server, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I have a web server running, just that there is a problem when entering with any other user who is not an administrator in the system, requests access but does not let you enter because they do not have permission, and try with the permissions on the folder, the permissions for the iss user. And keep marking the same I leave here a screen.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the filesystem permissions on your server's home directory don't allow read access for other users.

On the server, bring up the Properties window for c:\inetpub\wwwroot, see who has the rights. In order to avoid the username/password prompt, a user needs at least Read.

Comment: Add an image of the permissions of the folder to the iis web server

Comment: Is anonymous auth enabled for the site root in IIS settings?